# PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy empezando en PHP, y creo que a mi código le falta algo para que pueda funcionar, pues se produce el error que mencioné.

El código de mi mysqlcon.php es:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host=;
$username=;
$password= ;
$db_name=;
$link=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot Connect");
mysqli_select_db("$link", "$db_name")or die("Cannot Select DB");
?>
```

Comment: Quita las comillas a las variables: Aquí: `$link=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Cannot Connect");` y aquí: `mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name) or die ("Cannot Select DB");` y pon los datos de host, username, password, db_name... en el código real, claro está.

Comment: Hola Esteban, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa al [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y cómo funciona en general. Un saludo.

Comment: **También**, puedes conectar y elegir la base de datos en una sola llamada: `$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);`. [Revisa la documentación](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php).

Answer (score 1):

### El problema

El error:

> Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

significa que aquí:

<s>`$link=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("Cannot Connect");`</s>

tú obtendrías normalmente un **objeto del tipo `mysqli`**

pero luego en esta línea lo tratas como una cadena al escribirlo entre comillas:

<s>`mysqli_select_db("$link", "$db_name")or die("Cannot Select DB");`</s>

---

### Soluciones

#### La más óptima

Seleccionar la base de datos cuando creas la conexión, así haces una sola llamada:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
```

#### Le menos óptima

Dejarlo como lo tienes, pero quitando las comillas. Lo único que justifica esta segunda forma sería que vayas a cambiar de base de datos en algún momento... De hecho, el [Manual dice lo siguiente](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php) al respecto:

> Esta función debería ser usada solo para cambiar la base de datos por
>   defecto para la conexión. **Se puede seleccionar la base de datos por
>   defecto en el cuarto parámetro de la función `mysqli_connect()`**.

```
$link=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Cannot Connect");
mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name) or die ("Cannot Select DB");
```

El uso de comillas en las otras variables no da error porque siguen siendo cadenas, pero no tiene sentido usar comillas en ellas.

---

#### También

Puedes usar el [estilo Orientado a Objetos](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) para crear la conexión. Es más moderno y comprensible.

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
if ($link->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $link->connect_errno . ") " . $link->connect_error;
}
```

En ese caso, conviene que todo el código sub-siguiente sea orientado a objetos.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $host=;
    $username=;
    $password= ;
    $db_name=;
    $link=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name)or die("Cannot Connect");
```

Te comento lo siguiente de tu código

Las variables no van entre comillas pues de lo contrario lo lee como cadenas de texto
Como estas usando mysqli, pasas incluso el nombre de la base de datos en la primer función de connect, no necesias la que dice select_database