# Problemas con PHP y SQL (expects parameter 1 to be sqli)

Tags: php, mysql

Intentaba abrir mi archivo .php desde el localhost y me salieron los siguientes errores:

**Primer error:**

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion.php on line 8

**Código del primer error:**

```html
<?php
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','*****');
define('DB_USER','*****');
define('DB_PASS','*****');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME,$con);
?>
```

Segundo error:

> Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 4
>   Por favor llene todos los campos.

Código del segundo error:

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once "conexion.php";
    if($_POST['usuario'] == '' or $_POST['password'] == '' or $_POST['repassword'] == '')

    {
        echo 'Por favor llene todos los campos.';
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
        $rec = mysql_query($sql);
        $verificar_usuario = 0;

        while($result = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
        {
            if($result->usuario == $_POST['usuario'])
            {
                $verificar_usuario = 1;
            }
        }

        if($verificar_usuario)
        {
            if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['repassword'])
            {
                $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario,password) VALUES ('$usuario','$password')";
                mysql_query($sql);

                echo 'Usted se ha registrado correctamente.';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105641/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli). Ese error aparece cuando pasas los parámetros al revés... el primer parámetro a pasar es el de la conexión `$con`.  Otra cosa a tomar en cuenta es que puedes seleccionar la base de datos al momento de conectar, es mejor. El uso de `mysqli_select_db` se justificaría solamente en el caso de [querer usar dos bases de datos distintas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/159302/29967).

Comment: Sergio, como te ponía en otra pregunta que hiciste, debes hacer algo de búsqueda e investigación. Esta pregunta ya se ha hecho (múltiples veces) en el sitio. Además, es importante que aprendas a hacer preguntas de calidad: céntrate en un problema por pregunta (ésta contiene varios errores), pon títulos descriptivos a tus preguntas (“problemas con PHP y MySQL no es un buen título porque no sintetiza el problema, podría ser cualquier cosa)... lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Aparte, y no relacionado con la pregunta en sí, el código que compartes es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público. Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP y corrige los problemas de tu código (usa sentencias preparadas en lugar de concatenar cadenas para formar la sentencia sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion.php on line 8

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','*****');
define('DB_USER','*****');
define('DB_PASS','*****');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME);
?>
```

**mysqli_select_db(conexion, nombre_base_de_datos)**
Tenías los parámetros de la función al revés, prueba a ver que tal.

> Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 4 Por favor llene todos los campos.

En cuanto a este error te esta diciendo que la superglobal $_POST no contiene la clave 'usuario', por lo que entra en el if y te muestra el mensaje del echo.
Un saludo.

Comment: Querrás decir el segundo no? el del usuario

Comment: Que debo hacer en ese caso, quiero decir, si $_POST no contiene la clave 'usuario'

Comment: Si, perdón me equivoqué

Comment: Tienes el html en el mismo archivo que php?

Comment: No, los tengo separados, ¿puede ser por eso?

Comment: No, mira que en tu html, en el input donde introduces el usuario, el atributo  name coincida seguro al 100% con el índice que haces referencia en el $_POST. Es decir, input name="usuario", $_POST["usuario"], las mayúsculas y minusculas influyen, deben estar exactamente igual.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que puedes pasar el nombre de la base de datos a la función `mysqli_connect` como último parámetro, por ejemplo: `$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);`. De ese modo ya tienes una conexión activa apuntando a `DB_NAME` y evitas tener que, una vez creado el objeto de conexión, hacer una llamada suplementaria a `mysqli_select_db`, cuyo uso **sería justificado solamente en el caso de querer cambiar de una base de datos a otra**, @sergio.

Comment: Vale @A.Cedano, muchas gracias!

Comment: Tengo un lío terrible en el html, voy a hacerlo de nuevo. ¿Podrías decirme como debería ser el código para conseguir que funcione sin errores?